# How to add links that select the preferred language (CodeIgniter's Language Class)?

Tags: codeigniter

I just finished this tutorial:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Internationalization_and_the_Template_Parser_Class/

but now I want some links to change `english` to `spanish`

I know how to change it by modifying the controller `example.php`:

```
# Load language
$this->lang->load('example', 'english');
```

But I can't figure out how to do that in the view file `example.php`

What's the simplest and best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
function set_lang($lang)
{
    return $this->config->set_item('language', $lang);
}
```

You should also add the 'language' library to the autoload config and then just put the $this->lang->line() to the appropriate places.